# How do I build nasm files with Scons?

Tags: linux, nasm, scons

Running on Linux, where the default Scons assembler is "as", this generates an error:

```
env = Environment( tools=['nasm', 'default'] )
env.StaticLibrary( 'module', 'src.asm' )
```

during compile, this is called:

```
as -o test.o test.asm
```

Alternatively, if I remove 'default' from the tools:

```
env = Environment( tools=['nasm'] )
```

Python throws:

```
AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'StaticLibrary':
```

I want to build a static library using nasm as the assembler.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build static libraries, you have to add the "ar" Tool to your Environment as well:

```
env = Environment(tools=['ar', 'nasm'])
```

As an alternative, adding the "nasm" Tool **after** loading all the defaults (which includes the standard as/gas assembler) should work too:

```
env = Environment(tools=['default', 'nasm'])
```

, because this will redefine the "$AS" env variable to "nasm" as required.

Comment: +1. I didn't know that the `tools` variable was order-dependent.

Comment: All assignments to (Environment) variables are order-dependent, they simply have to be. ;)

Comment: Right. But I meant to say that I didn't know that the ordering inside the list mattered.